# ¿Cómo centrar un icono de FontAwesome dentro de un div?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, font-awesome

Hola tengo 3 div alineados con bootstrap y quiero dentro de cada div centrar el icono.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-5x fa-align-center"></i>
     <h3 class="text-center">Diseño web</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
   </div>
```

Estoy usando la clase fa-align-center y nada. con la clase de bootstrap text-center tampoco me funciona.

Answer (score 5):

Deberías añadirle la clase al contenedor, no al icono. Es decir, deberías de añadirle la clase `text-center` al div que contiene el icono y no al propio icono.

He creado un `div` que englobe al icono (y que contenga la clase anterior) para que el resto de textos no se centren, tal y como me has planteado en los comentarios, y solo se centre el icono.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-5x"></i></div>
   <h3 class="text-center">Diseño web</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: si funciona pero me centra todo el contenido de los divs y los parrafos no los quiero centrar.

Comment: ya lo he solucionado. gracias francisco

Comment: @RafaelHernández Lo que puedes hacer es englobar el icono en otro `div` y asignarle la clase `text-center` a este último de manera que solo afecte al icono.

Answer (score 0):

La clase `text-center` debes ponerla dentro de `<i>` quitala del `div` que la engloba